# Rspec error for failing test different than the error seen in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, bdd, rspec3

Im using RSpec v3.1.0 and Capybara v2.3.0 in my rails app.I have the following in my **spec/features/user_creates_todo_spec.rb**.

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'User creates todo' do 
    scenario 'successfully' do
        visit root_path

        click_on 'Add a new todo'
        fill_in 'Title', with: 'Buy milk'
        click_on 'Submit'

        expect(page).to have_css '.todos li', text: 'Buy milk'
    end
end
```

Then in my **app/views/todos/index.html.erb**, i added the following:

```
<%= link_to "Add a new todo", new_todo_path %>
```

When i run **rspec spec/features/user_creates_todo_spec.rb**,the test fails with an error **Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find link or button "Add a new todo"**

However, im expecting the error to be: **Undefined local variable or method 'new_todo_path'**, since i already have the link defined in my view . And the strange thing is that when i run the rails server and navigate to the root path from the browser i see the undefined local variable or method 'new_todo_path' error.Also, i see the undefined path error when i just run rake from the root of my app. So, why is it that when i run the spec file individually using rspec i see a different error even though i have the link added to the page ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that Capybara is opening a browser session, which runs in a new process, and navigating to a path, just as a user would. Your Rails app may indeed by raising an exception, but Capybara is only looking at the response in the browser -- it doesn't know what is happening in the process where the Rails server runs. So it dutifully visits the url, gets the 500 error page, looks for the link and (of course) fails to find it.

Answer (score 0):

<del>That is because the link is not added to the page. `new_todo_path` is not defined which likely means that you haven't added the proper routes for it in your `routes.rb` file.</del>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But then why is that when i just run rake from my project root, the expected error of Undefined local variable or method 'new_todo_path' is shown ? . As i have mentioned in my question above i have the link_to code in my app/views/todos/index.html.erb, still when i run the spec individually using rspec, it complains of the missing link instead of the undefined route.

Comment: Potentially related: [https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/660](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/660)